# Do i really need to factory reset/data wipe for cynogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod

im new here, the question is in the title. I would like to use cynogenmod for when im listening to music, so that i can change the track just by using the volume buttons. I don't plan on installing custom ROM on my phone since there is none available.

Im using Samsung Galaxy Ace II (rooted) V. 4.0.4

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you think Cyanogenmod is, but it *is* a custom ROM. It replaces the whole OS on your phone. You need to factory-reset when flashing it because the built-in apps and settings are (or might be) saved in a different format to stock Android: if Cyanogenmod tried to read the settings saved by stock Android, it would go wrong.

If all you want is to change track using your volume keys, you don't need Cyanogenmod for that: just install a music player app that offers that feature.